# how to deploy WPF application having Crystal Report

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have two crystal reports in my Project.

I am having SaleBillReport.rpt file in My project.
which is being loaded using report object method whose code is given below.

First report is shown as -

**Case 1:**

```
 SaleBillReport rptObj = new SaleBillReport();//My Rpt file name
 rptObj.SetDataSource(_ReportDataSet);

 _reportViewer.ReportSource = rptObj;
```

Second report is shown as -

**Case 2:**

```
ReportDocument objReportDoc = new ReportDocument();
objReportDoc.Load(@"D:\\" + "MyReport.rpt");

ReportViewerNew.ReportSource = objReportDoc;
```

My problem is that while deploying this project i don't need to Put any .rpt file anywhere.
It is in-built in My application.

But i have to put my 2nd .rpt file to any path for display.(i don't want to put anywhere)
So how i in build case 2 .rpt file in my project during Deployment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which deployment method are you using? Setup project or click once or something else?

Comment: just building application in Release Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection to find out where your application is installed

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly

[Method explantion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx)

and ask the folder of that assembly and add your report filename to that path...

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be using reflection, but it is little tricky.

Second one and the simpler one would be using `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

For that, modify your Case 2 code like this -

```
ReportDocument objReportDoc = new ReportDocument();
string reportPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "MyReport.rpt");
objReportDoc.Load(reportPath);

ReportViewerNew.ReportSource = objReportDoc;
```

and for your report to be always permanent at the current directory location, just go to the properties of your MyReport.rpt file and select **Copy Always** or **Copy if newer**.

Comment: If i will choose Copy always then it will create .rpt files within .exe folder. i don't wanna do that.